# TextBlock binding displays class name instead of empty string

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have the following Windows RT app. I bind a List of Strings to an ItemsControl of TextBlocks. This will display the empty strings as "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]" instead of just an empty string. I would like it to display an empty string instead of the type of the DataContext.

code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new List<string>() { "", "not empty string" };
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]
non empty string
```

I made the same example with traditional wpf and it displays the empty strings correctly.

**Edit**
This outputs the same thing.

code behind:

```
public class Model
{
    private readonly List<string> items = new List<string>() { "", "non empty string" };

    public List<string> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
    } 
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Model();
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it seems like a bug in the platform, but anyways - this doesn't seem like the typical mainstream way to use bindings. People typically either set ItemsSource directly to a collection or use a view model type that exposes a collection property that you would then bind to your ItemsControl's ItemsSource. I've never seen anyone setting a DataContext to a collection or see a good reason for that.

Comment: This is just a sample. The application I'm building assigns the DataContext to a ViewModel which has a property of type List<String>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually see that it's a bug (or odd intentional feature) by adding a Converter to the `TextBlock` `Binding`.

Add a static resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:NoNullsConverter x:Key="fixNulls"></local:NoNullsConverter>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then change the Binding to reference the Converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource fixNulls}}" FontSize="25"/>
```

Add this class:

```
public class NoNullsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // This converts the value object to the string to display.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is string ? value : "";         
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you put a break point on the `return` statement, you'll see that the first value that is passed actually is the entire list. Yes, unexpected. However, if you use this Converter as written, it handles that oddity and just returns a more logical empty string.

Or, you can do something more *interesting* and create a simple wrapper class:

```
public class StringContext
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator StringContext(string value)
    {
        return new StringContext() { Value = value };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

With this class, you can just use the Binding as expected:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25"/>
```

However, you would need to use a different class type in the declaration of the List:

```
DataContext = new List<StringContext>() { "", "not empty string" };
```

Using the implicit cast, it "just works" as it converts the `String` to a `StringContext`. Yes, it would add the overhead of creating an unnecessary class, but it does work. :) I'd prefer the Converter option.

Comment: I also created a converter to see what was going on. I guess it's a bug. I will use the converter work around. Thanks!

Comment: Ran into this bug also.  I was working more with code-behind, so I think I have a little more information.  It appears that the binding property 'TargetNullValue' is broken.  If you give it an empty string, you get the behavior described above.  If you feed it a single space ' ', then it fills the null values in with the single space.  They are likely doing some 'IsNullOrEmpty' behind the scenes when the just wanted to compare to null.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't explain why, but it works as expected when you directly set the `ItemsSource` property:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    ...
</ItemsControl>

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    itemsControl.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "", "not empty string" };
}
```

---

I also tried this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    ...
</ItemsControl>

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Items = new List<string>() { "", "not empty string" };
    DataContext = this;
}

public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }
```

but it results in displaying

> **TextBlockBindingTest.MainPage**
>
> **not empty string**

Apparently, when the item binding evaluates to *null or empty*, it falls back to the inherited DataContext. I guess this is a bug in WinRT.

---

Alternatively, you may also set the `Name` property of the MainPage class and write a binding like this:

```
<Page ... x:Name="mainPage">
...
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=mainPage}">
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

and not set the DataContext:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Items = new List<string>() { "", "not empty string" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or try set binding code behind:

```
//list is ItemsControl
var bin = new Binding();
var mylist = new List<string>(){"","not empty string"};
bin.Source = mylist;
list.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty,bin);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This works, but not because it's code-behind. It works because you don't set a DataContext, but the Binding Source instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I stumbled upon a simpler solution.  This is, no doubt, a bug.  Same code in WPF gives the expected results.  The source of the bug is the TargetNullValue Property which doesn't interpret empty strings properly.  To get around the bug, you can either use the IValueConverter suggested above (Converter solutions have performance issues from my experience) or use:

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetNullValue=' '}" FontSize="25"/>
```